# Compiling PHP and installing it under one directory

Tags: php, directory-structure, make, configure

I have to compile a few versions of PHP in work but I need an apache service for each version running like we have on Windows. However the configure options seem to have different folders for everything. I was wondering if there was an easy way to configure so when I make install it is all in one folder, with all the extensions in ext etc rather than scattered around the system.

I want to compile 5.5.1, 5.3.27, 5.2.17 and 4.3.11.

Now this wouldn't be a problem with just one PHP version but with multiple versions things will probably be overwritten/conflicted in other ways.

Say I want everything to go to `/php/5.5.1/`

./configure --prefix=`/php/5.5.1/`

How else is this to be configured to put everything in that folder? Has anyone else done this?

Comment: Do you *have* to manually compile them? What distro are you using, and doesn't it have packages for the various versions?

Comment: I'm using mint and I've searched the default repos and they only seem to have one version. I've searched for php linux binaries on google to no avail. I'm guessing I have to compile them unless there is some good trusted repo which has many versions?

Comment: Don't install under `/php/5.5.1`. Install under `/opt/php/5.5.1`, that's what `/opt` is for (a bit like `Program Files` in Windows).

Answer (score 1):

The `--prefix` will make sure all man pages, config files and includes are compiled in that location. The `--exec-prefix` will do the same only for executables and extensions

```
./configure --prefix=/php/5.5.1/ --exec-prefix=/php/5.5.1//exec
```

Comment: So `./configure --prefix=/php/5.5.1/ --exec-prefix=/php/5.5.1/exec` should pack every file into `/php/5.5.1/`?

Comment: Except for the Apache module all files will go there.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try using [`phpbrew`](https://github.com/c9s/phpbrew) instead of installing these your self. `phpbrew` is a frontend that can help with the managing, switching and compiling of different versions of PHP. It works similarly to [`perlbrew`](http://perlbrew.pl/) for Perl.

#### Example

To see what versions you have setup:

```
$ phpbrew known
Available stable versions:
    php-5.3.10
    php-5.3.9
    php-5.3.8
    php-5.3.7
```

To install a version:

```
$ phpbrew -d install --test php-5.4.0
```

To use a version:

```
$ phpbrew use php-5.4.0RC7
```

To make your default a different version:

```
$ phpbrew switch php-5.4.0
```

#### What about Apache

`phpbrew` can provide you the ability to include variants, so that you can include things such as mysql support or Apache support (`apxs`).

```
$ phpbrew install php-5.3.10 +mysql +apxs2
```

If you have you'r own version of Apache installed, you can direct `phpbrew` to it's location:

```
$ phpbrew install php-5.3.10 +mysql +apxs2=/usr/local/bin/apxs2
```

You'll need to maintain different versions of Apache `httpd.conf` files for each individual PHP, if you're using it with a web server.

Comment: I'll have a look into this thanks :) The other answer seems more simple and would allow me to setup different apaches pointing to different php inis on different ports. But I'll see if this can too?

Comment: @foxyfennec - this could be done with phpbrew too. After you set it up all your PHP's will be self contained as well. You can point into this tree for the various `php.ini` files.